# Trig angles simplifying in worksheet

Tags: output-formatting

I would like to generate a table of trig questions such as:

```
Table[RandomChoice[{Sin, Cos, Tan}][
RandomInteger[{-180, 450}] \[Degree]] //
TraditionalForm, {3}, {4}] // TableForm
```

does. MMA however evaluates this to acute angles.

What syntax can be used to keep the evaluation as sin(200˚) say?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's just for show, you can just convert the angle to a string:

```
 Table[RandomChoice[{Sin, Cos, Tan}][
 ToString@RandomInteger[{-180, 450}] \[Degree]] //
 TraditionalForm, {3}, {4}] // TableForm
```

Comment: yes, just for show, although ideally I would also like to evaluate the output.